# Magento 2.1.7 Open Source. No system configuration

Tags: magento-2.1, admin

I have just installed an empty copy of Magento 2.1.7 using Installatron to a sub folder of my website (mysite.com/store) where mysite.com is a Joomla CMS.

I am trying to set up so the entire front end uses https, and found a guide that said to navigate to: `System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Redirect options`

I can go to the admin panel using the mysite.com/store/[randomcharacters] and log in, but when I do there are no system configuration settings:
[image]

I can't find anywhere that says there is a separate "system" admin panel, so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 2, you can find all configuration under `STORES`menu.

For update website URLs go to: `STORES > Settings > Configuration > GENERAL > Web`.

Thank you.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.